# grab fields from billing checkoutpage

Tags: magento-1.9, php, event-observer

mates. I'm using simple solution to **grab fields from billing** that must work , but it doesn't .

just part of config, where we are creating observer :

```
       <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
            <observers>
                <sale_recomendation_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Field_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveCustomData</method>
                </sale_recomendation_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
```

my **Model/Observer.php**

```
    public function saveCustomData($observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();

        $fieldVal = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();

        foreach ($fieldVal as $key => $value){
            echo $key." -- ".$value;
        }
        die;

        //$order->setSaleRecomendation($var);
        if(!empty($var)){
            Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->setOrderId($order->getId())
            ->setData(array('sale_recomendation' => $var))
            ->save();
        }
    }
```

and, ofcourse, part of modified ...persistent/checkout/onepage/**billing.phtml**

```
     <li class="fields">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="billing:sale_recomendation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Sale Recomendation') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry"
                    name="field[sale_recomendation]"
                    value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getQuote()->getSaleRecomendation()) ?>"
                    title="<?php echo $this->__('Sale Recomendation') ?>"  
                    id="billing:sale_recomendation" />
        </div>
    </div>
 </li>
```

my foreach echo show me this : form_key -- fgfwhmetEgTqHteo . 
no one billing field there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method`event to observe

Comment: now it showing shipping_method -- flatrate_flatrate  after 4th step and form_key -- fgfwhmetEgTqHteo when trying save 6th. nothing more )

Answer (score 0):

Almost solved. I'm using one more observer `sales_quote_save_before` and save field directly in billing step with help of `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData()` and getting it here: `checkout_type_onepage_save_order`, but anyway, This error appeared:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `setSaleRecomendation()` on null in/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Speroteck/Field/Model/Observer.php on line **64**

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the value in `observer`

```
$field=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('field');
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

```
   <sales_quote_save_before>
            <observers>
                <save_before>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Field_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveQuoteBefore</method>
                </save_before>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_save_before>
```

+

```
    public function saveQuoteBefore($evt){
    $post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();

    if(isset($post['field']['sale_recomendation'])){
        $var = $post['field']['sale_recomendation'];
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('sale_recomendation', $var);
    }
}
```

AND

```
            <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
            <observers>
                <sale_recomendation_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Field_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveCustomData</method>
                </sale_recomendation_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
```

+

```
    public function saveCustomData($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $order = $event->getOrder();

    $var = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('sale_recomendation');
    $order->setSaleRecomendation($var);

}
```